# ImportError when importing Keras using Anaconda

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I am writing a python script and want to call it from other applications, so I need it to be callable directly from `cmd`.

The problem is that I use Anaconda to manage my environments, and I need to run the script inside a specific environment.

I searched how to run a script via cmd using the anaconda environment, and found that instead of just calling `python`, I could specify `python` executable in my virtual environment folder, but when I try that, I get the following error when trying to import `load_model` from `keras`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import load_model
  File "D:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "D:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import np_utils
  File "D:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "D:\Users\Rodolfo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

If I try to run the same script directly on Anaconda prompt, the script runs completely as expected, my issue is strictly running it from the standard prompt instead of Anaconda's.

What could be the issue of this `ImportError`?

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is tensorflow as backend? Is this tensorflow GPU (which version)?  If yes, share please the CUDA drivers version.

Comment: Using tensorflow backend with CUDA9. But i don't think this would be the issue, since via the anaconda prompt the imports runs normally